# NSString defining variable to go into format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I'm working on homework that is asking me to return a full sentence indicating my favorite cheese. I have written out the code below, but I'm not sure where to define `cheeseName`. Also, how would I test the code to see if it returns the right `cheeseName`, `NSLog()`?

This is my .m file

```
#import "StringCheese.h"

@implementation StringCheese

- (NSString *) favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:(NSString *)cheeseName {
/* WORK HERE */
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My favorite cheese is %@.", cheeseName];
/ My answer is the code above/
}
```

This is my other .m file:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "StringCheese.h"

@interface StringCheeseTests : XCTestCase

@property (nonatomic, strong) StringCheese *stringCheese;

@end

@implementation StringCheeseTests

- (void)setUp
{
[super setUp];
// Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
self.stringCheese = [[StringCheese alloc] init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
// Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
[super tearDown];
}

- (void)testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks {
NSString *ricottaString = @"ricotta";
NSString *favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:ricottaString];

XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is ricotta.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");

NSString *goatString = @"goat";
favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:goatString];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is goat.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");
```

}

EDIT: Result of when I run it

```
12:21:17.116 xctest[13545:2066149] _XCT_testBundleReadyWithProtocolVersion:minimumVersion: reply received
12:21:17.129 xctest[13545:2066149]  _IDE_startExecutingTestPlanWithProtocolVersion:16
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2015-11-29 12:21:17.150
Test Suite 'StringCheeseTests' started at 2015-11-29 12:21:17.153
Test Case '-[StringCheeseTests testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks]' started.
Test Case '-[StringCheeseTests testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks]' passed  (0.005 seconds).
Test Suite 'StringCheeseTests' passed at 2015-11-29 12:21:17.162.
Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.005 (0.009) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2015-11-29 12:21:17.165.
 Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.005 (0.015) seconds

Test session log:
/var/folders/c0/1phmslcx35ngtg42z44yk75h0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-11-29_12:21:08-HEws7M.log

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having with this code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm writing the code correctly to indicate my favorite cheese. The homework states the following: `Creates a sentence indicating a favorite cheese.
 
 Example usage:
 
 @code
 NSString *fullSentence = [cheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:@"cheddar"];
 // fullSentence is "My favorite cheese is cheddar."
 @endcode
 
 @param cheeseName
 The name of the favorite cheese
 
 @return Returns a full sentence indicating a favorite cheese.
 */
`

Comment: Well, what happens when you run it?

Comment: added output to the post

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To print out the value add :

```
NSLog(@"%@", favouriteCheese);
```

At the end of the  - (void)testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks method so it looks like:

```
- (void)testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks {
NSString *ricottaString = @"ricotta";
NSString *favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:ricottaString];

XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is ricotta.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");

NSString *goatString = @"goat";
favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:goatString];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is goat.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");

NSLog(@"%@", favoriteCheese);
}
```